# preventing log_on_success in xinetd

Tags: logging, xinetd

I'd like to prevent a particular xinetd check from logging START/EXIT messages as it's a lot of logging I don't need.

Is ther a way to set `log_on_success = NONE` or something? I'm able to find ways of adding/removing individual items from the check, but not preventing success logging entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some context, be aware that many Xinetd configurations now have cumulative log settings by default- meaning that service-based log settings are *appended to* the default settings in `/etc/xinetd.conf`. You will see this if the configs use `+=` instead of `=` to assign their `log_on_success` and `log_on_failure` settings.

The quick fix is to either use `=` in your service-based configs under `/etc/xinetd.d/` to override the defaults, or else you can blank out the default settings for `log_on_success` or `log_on_failure` in `/etc/xinetd.conf` and let the service-based configs "append" their own settings as-needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the logging of a particular xinetd service entirely simply redirect the log to /dev/null?

```
{
  ...
  log_type = FILE /dev/null 
}
```

Comment: I'd like to keep the `log_on_failure` if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    ...
    log_on_success =
}
```